# Drag Event on element already drawn

Tags: d3.js, drag

I have problem with the drag event on elemets already drawn, if I need to move them I have to click "Circle" Link and then works, the event dissapears after select another option.

It is important that event stays binded althought another option be selected.

I tried adding this line but doesn't work.

```
d3.select(this).call(d3.drag().on('start', dragstarted).on('drag', dragged).on('end', dragended));
```

[Link Example](https://circulable-checker.000webhostapp.com/svg/)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title>FAM</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v4.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    var svg = d3.select('#svf');//.on("mousedown", mousedown).on("mouseup", mouseup);
                    var container = svg.append('g');
                    var pxy = new Array(), line, i = 0, j = 0;

                    for (i = 0; i < 500; i = i + 10) {
                        container.append('line').attr('x1', i).attr('y1', 0).attr('x2', i).attr('y2', 500).attr('stroke', '#CFCECE').attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('fill', 'none');
                    }

                    for (j = 0; j < 500; j = j + 10) {
                        container.append('line').attr('x1', 1).attr('y1', j).attr('x2', 500).attr('y2', j).attr('stroke', '#CFCECE').attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('fill', 'none');
                    }

                    function main() {
                        pxy = new Array();
                        var coords = d3.mouse(this), x = coords[0], y = coords[1];
                        var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                        var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');

                        if (conv == 1) {
                            pxy = new Array();
                            container.append('circle').attr('cx', x).attr('cy', y).attr('r', 30).attr('stroke-width', 2).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('fill', 'transparent').on('click', clicked).call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted).on("drag", dragged).on("end", dragended));
                        }

                        if (conv == 2) {
                            pxy = new Array();
                            container.append('rect').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).attr('width', 60).attr('height', 60).attr('stroke-width', 2).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('fill', 'transparent').on('click', clicked).call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted).on("drag", dragged).on("end", dragended));
                        }

                        if (conv == 3) {

                        }

                        if (conv == 4) {
                            pxy[pxy.length] = x;
                            pxy[pxy.length] = y;

                            pxy[pxy.length] = x;
                            pxy[pxy.length] = y + 30;

                            pxy[pxy.length] = x + 160;
                            pxy[pxy.length] = y + 30;

                            pxy[pxy.length] = x + 160;
                            pxy[pxy.length] = y;

                            container.append('polyline').attr("stroke", '#000').attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('fill', 'transparent').on('click', clicked).attr('points', pxy).call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted).on("drag", dragged).on("end", dragended));
                            pxy = new Array();
                        }
                    }

                    svg.on('click', main);

                    function mousedown() {
                        var m = d3.mouse(this);
                        line = container.append("line")
                                .attr("x1", m[0])
                                .attr("y1", m[1])
                                .attr("x2", m[0])
                                .attr("y2", m[1]).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('stroke-width', 2).attr('fill', 'transparent').on('click', clicked).call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted).on("drag", dragged).on("end", dragended));
                        svg.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                    }

                    function mousemove() {
                        var m = d3.mouse(this);
                        line.attr('x2', m[0]).attr('y2', m[1]);
                    }

                    function mouseup() {
                        svg.on('mousemove', null);
                        svg.on('click', null);
                        console.log('...');
                    }

                    function dragstarted(d) {
                        d3.select(this).raise().classed('active', true);
                    }

                    function dragged(d) {
                        var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                        var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');

                        if (conv == 1) {
                            d3.select(this).attr('cx', +d3.select(this).attr('cx') + d3.event.dx);
                            d3.select(this).attr('cy', +d3.select(this).attr('cy') + d3.event.dy);
                        }

                        if (conv == 2) {
                            d3.select(this).attr('x', +d3.select(this).attr('x') + d3.event.dx);
                            d3.select(this).attr('y', +d3.select(this).attr('y') + d3.event.dy);
                        }

                        if (conv == 3 || conv == 4) {
                            this.x = this.x || 0;
                            this.y = this.y || 0;
                            this.x += d3.event.dx;
                            this.y += d3.event.dy;
                            d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.x + ',' + this.y + ')');
                        }
                    }


                    function dragended(d) {
                        d3.select(this).classed('active', false);
                    }

                    d3.select('body').on('keydown', function () {
                        if (d3.event.keyCode === 27) {
                            pxy = new Array();
                            $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            $('#lnk_polyline').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                            svg.on('mousemove', null);

                            var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                            var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');
                            if (conv == 3) {
                                svg.on('click', mousedown);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    function clicked(d, i) {
                        var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                        var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');
                        if (conv == 20) {
                            d3.select(this).remove();
                        } else {
                         /*This line doesn´t work*/
                            var element = $(this).prop('tagName');
                            if (element == 'circle' || element == 'rect') {
                                d3.select(this).call(d3.drag().on('start', dragstarted).on('drag', dragged).on('end', dragended));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $('#lnk_circle').click(function () {
                        svg.on('click', main);
                        $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_polyline').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                        return false;
                    });

                    $('#lnk_rectangle').click(function () {
                        svg.on('click', main);
                        $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_polyline').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                        return false;
                    });

                    $('#lnk_polyline').click(function () {
                        svg.on('click', main);
                        $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                        return false;
                    });

                    $('#lnk_line').click(function () {
                        svg.on('click', mousedown).on("dblclick", mouseup);
                        $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_polyline').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                        return false;
                    });

                    $('#lnk_erase').click(function () {
                        svg.on('click', null);
                        $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_polyline').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                        return false;
                    });

                    //$('#svg').find('g').find('circle,rect,line').on("dblclick", clicked).call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted).on("drag", dragged).on("end", dragended));
                });
            </script>
            <style>
                line,circle,rect,polyline{ shape-rendering:crispEdges;} 
            </style>                
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="dv_conv" style="float: left;width:200px;border:1px solid #000;margin-right: 1px">
                <a href="#" id="lnk_circle" data-pressed="0" data-conv="1">Circle</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_rectangle" data-pressed="0" data-conv="2">Rectangle</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_line" data-pressed="0" data-conv="3">Line</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_polyline" data-pressed="0" data-conv="4">PolyLine</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_erase" data-pressed="0" data-conv="20">Erase</a><br/>
            </div>

            <div id="dv_familiogram" style="float: left;width:500px;height: 500px;border:1px solid #000;overflow: hidden">

                <svg id="svf"  style="width:500px;height:500px"></svg>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you select actions in `dragged` function based on Link which was clicked, not based on type of shape you have dragged.

You can replace your `dragged` function with a number of functions (each for a certain shape type):

```
function dragged_conv1(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('cx', +d3.select(this).attr('cx') + d3.event.dx);
        d3.select(this).attr('cy', +d3.select(this).attr('cy') + d3.event.dy);
}

function dragged_conv2(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('x', +d3.select(this).attr('x') + d3.event.dx);
        d3.select(this).attr('y', +d3.select(this).attr('y') + d3.event.dy);
}

function dragged_conv34(d) {
        this.x = this.x || 0;
        this.y = this.y || 0;
        this.x += d3.event.dx;
        this.y += d3.event.dy;
        d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.x + ',' + this.y + ')');
}
```

and bind each function to each shape in your `main` function:

```
if (conv == 1) {
    pxy = new Array();
    container.append('circle') ... .on("drag", dragged_conv1)...;
}

if (conv == 2) {
    pxy = new Array();
    container.append('rect') ... .on("drag", dragged_conv2)...;
}

if (conv == 4) {
// ... some code here ...

    container.append('polyline') ... .on("drag", dragged_conv34)...;
    pxy = new Array();
}
```